# Asymptotics of Riemann-Lebesgue type integral

Tags: integration, asymptotics, spectral-theory

How to show that for $u \in L_{\mathbb{C}}^2$ and $a>0$,

$$\int_0^a u(t) \sin{\sqrt{\lambda}t} \,dt = o(e^{|Im\sqrt{\lambda}|a}),\text{ as } |\lambda| \rightarrow \infty$$

Note that $\lambda$ need not tend to infinity along the positive real axis.

Comment: First show that the result is true for $u(x)=e^{ikt\pi /a}$, then use density.